# which one is the true integration result with different expressions

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

We know
$$\int 1-{1\over u+1}\,du=u-\ln(u+1)+C$$ and
$$\int {u\over u+1}\,du = u+1-\ln(u+1)+C$$

Why these two equations have different integration results although I only change the way to express the equation?
Are both equations true?

Comment: In the first one, $\log\equiv\ln$ and the additional $1$ in the second is just a constant. Take the derivative of each result and see if you obtain the integrand and see what happens.

Comment: Thankyou!! if it is a constant so it doesnt matter to use either one of them? Im working on differential equations actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Both logs should be to base $e$, that is $\ln$.

(2) The constants are *arbitrary*.  They need not be the same value.

So indeed we can say:  $$~~~~~~~~u-\ln (u+1)+c_1~=~u+1-\ln(u+1)+c_2\\\therefore\quad c_1=1+c_2$$

Comment: Ok!! So it means both of them true right? Because in differential equations, after got the result then change the constant to another sign like A or something so it is arbitrary and doesnt affect the result(?)

Comment: Yes, that is it.  If $c$ is an arbitrary constant, $c+1$ is also an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Thankyou!! And for example i have two equation on right and left and integrate both of them, is it matter where to put the constant? can i put either in right or left?